# Checking if a string is a palindrome using a stack

Tags: c, string, stack, palindrome

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *link;
}StackNode;

void insertData(StackNode **);
void push(StackNode **, char);
void checkData(StackNode **);
bool pop(StackNode **,char *);

char sent[20] = "";

void main()
{
   StackNode *stackTop;
   insertData(&stackTop);
   checkData(&stackTop);
   printf("\n");
   return;
}

void insertData(StackNode **stackTop)
{
    char c;
    int len;

    printf("Enter the Sentence\n");
    while( ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n'))
    {   
        if( ( ( c>='a' &&c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z')))
        {
            if((c>='A' && c<='Z'))
            {
                int rem;
                rem = c-'A';
                c='a' + rem;
            }
            push(stackTop,c);
            len = strlen(sent);
            sent[len++]=c;
            sent[len]='\0';
        }
    }
    printf("Letters are %s\n\n",sent);
}

void push(StackNode **stackTop,char c)
{
    StackNode *pNew;
    pNew = (StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    if(!pNew)
    {
        printf("Error 100:Out of memory\n");
        exit(100);
    }
    pNew->data = c;
    pNew->link = *stackTop;
    *stackTop = pNew;
}

void checkData(StackNode **stackTop)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while(pop(stackTop,&c))
    {
        if( c !=sent[i++])
        {
            printf("Not palindrome");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Palindrome");
}

bool pop(StackNode **stackTop,char *c)
{
    StackNode *pNew;
    pNew = *stackTop;
    if(pNew == NULL)
        return false;
    *c = pNew->data;
    *stackTop = pNew->link;
    printf("char poped %c\n",*c);
    free(pNew);
    return true;
}
```

I am able to pop each letter, after that the exe file is not working, I think I'm unable to check if the letters are same in reverse order. please help

I've been working all day to write this program,but I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the "using a stick" part...!?

Comment: @H2CO3, stick -> stack.  There's a pending edit if you want to approve it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a stack?

Comment: @sukunrt because i'm learning stacks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming in C, you should **always initialize pointers to NULL**. Because you didn't initialize the `StackNode *stackTop` (in main) it is pointing to garbage and is not null. So when you are checking for a palindrome, your pop method just keeps going off the end of the stack and never returns false because it never hits a null.  `StackNode *stackTop = NULL;` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
This helped me. I'll remember what you've said for ever.

Comment: @user2509877 You are welcome. Similarly, you should always memset the memory to 0 that is returned to you by malloc. `pNew = (StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(StackNode)); memset(pNew, 0, sizeof(StackNode));`  Also, think about what would happen if someone entered more than 20 characters. You are not checking that the input will fit into the `sent` array. You may want to put a check on the while loop in insert data that `len` is less than 20.

Comment: Just remember that C lets you do whatever you want with memory, so you have to be careful that you don't overwrite memory being used for something else and that what you expect to be in memory is actually there (ie if you expect it to be blank or null, it is).

Comment: "When programming in C, you should always initialize pointers to NULL" - I can't happen to be agreeing on that. It's not that simple.

Comment: @H2CO3 Could you elaborate?

Comment: @jlars62 why should we memset?
and is there a way in which there is no need to restrict the size of input string to 20 or some other number of letters? like, by using pointers or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to use the implicit call stack?

```
int is_pal(const char *begin, const char *end)
{
    if (*begin != *end)
        return 0;

    if ((end - begin) < 2)
        return *begin == *end;

    return is_pal(begin + 1, end - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but this is one way

put everything on the stack

and then pop everything comparing with the elements of the string from the start. something like this

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    push(s[i]);

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
   if (s[i] == pop())
      continue;